# Reading from textfile and spliting the values in C

Tags: c

what is the easiest way to separate following text file and print its values in this format

Comment: Its going to require code. The easiest way would be by having someone write the code **for you**. Don't expect it to be *that* easy. *What have you tried?*.

Comment: You may use multiple `strtok` or `strtok_r`.

Comment: homework like question is off topic.

Comment: Or just step through the data file with a pointer. You have great `[,:,]` delimiters to work with and -- time even starts at `00:00:00`.

Comment: There may be some confusion as to what is input and output in the question, but if the second block is input, then it looks like JSON and can be parsed as such. Otherwise, if the first block is input, then the asker can use standard string parsing and tokenizing functions.

Comment: The first block is output and the second block is JSON file. I am just trying to get some ideas before I start writing the code.

Answer (score 2):

If your input data are in JSON format, look at a C-based JSON parser, like [JSON-C](https://github.com/json-c/json-c) or [Jansson](https://github.com/akheron/jansson). Parse your data objects from JSON format and into some `struct` of your design, and then write a function to print out an array of `struct` elements to standard output, in a format of your choosing.